# How can I count how many SQL queries hibernate does in one Grails request?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, logging

I need to debug a Grails application with one really slow request. I have SQL logging but would like to see the amount of SQL-queries without counting them manually.

```
debug    'org.hibernate.SQL'
trace    'org.hibernate.type'
```

For eaxmple to have following line after each request (where x is the amount of all queries made to SQL server):

[2012-10-04 13:41:45,049][LoggingFilters] INFO  - Request finished in 8296 ms **and made x SQL statements**

After some googling this doesn't seem to be possible with Grails so maybe MySQL could provide the information?

Comment: Take a look at this [this](http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2012/06/gorm-false-sense-of-simplicity.html) blogpost. Here you can find a nice explanation how to test number of queries to database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by using Filters and Hibernate statistics.
Create class ExampleFilters.groovy in conf folder. This is the content of the class:

```
import org.hibernate.stat.Statistics
class ExampleFilters {

    def sessionFactory


    def filters = {
    // your filters here

        logHibernateStats(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
            Statistics stats = sessionFactory.statistics;
            if(!stats.statisticsEnabled) {stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true)}
                   }

        afterView = {
            Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics()
            double queryCacheHitCount  = stats.getQueryCacheHitCount();
            double queryCacheMissCount = stats.getQueryCacheMissCount();
            double queryCacheHitRatio = (queryCacheHitCount / ((queryCacheHitCount + queryCacheMissCount) ?: 1))
            println """
######################## Hibernate Stats ##############################################
Transaction Count:${stats.transactionCount}
Flush Count:${stats.flushCount}
Total Collections Fetched:${stats.collectionFetchCount}
Total Collections Loaded:${stats.collectionLoadCount}
Total Entities Fetched:${stats.entityFetchCount}
Total Entities Loaded:${stats.entityFetchCount}
Total Queries:${stats.queryExecutionCount}
queryCacheHitCount:${queryCacheHitCount}
queryCacheMissCount:${queryCacheMissCount}
queryCacheHitRatio:${queryCacheHitRatio}
######################## Hibernate Stats ##############################################
"""
            stats.clear()
        }

    }

    }

}
```

For reading more about various Hibernate statistics read this article:
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html

Also note that there is a performance impact when using this, so it should really be used only in development environment.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the resource I was looking for! `Statistics` in Hibernate API-documentation seems like a good place to take a look also.

Comment: Hey I made this into a [Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/log-hibernate-stats) in case it's helpful!  Credit also to the [original post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2011/11/07/grails-find-number-of-queries-executed-for-a-particular-request/) by Himanshu Seth.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered some low tech solutions like running the output through `wc -l`?

Comment: Unfortunately hibernate doesn't print queries per line in log. But you could count occurences of string "select". Of course you'd have to truncate the log file between each session. But works as a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

in grails use  `loggingSql`

```
dataSource {
 dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
 url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb"
 loggingSql = true
}
```

you’ll notice that all SQL statements Grails utilize will be logged.

Comment: Yes, I already have loggingSql enabled. What I need is the count of SQL statements in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As Burt Beckwith said in his blog post "Stuff I Learned Consulting" http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1570

SQL Logging

There are two ways to view SQL output from queries; adding logSql = true in DataSource.groovy and configuring Log4j loggers. The Log4j approach is a lot more flexible since it doesn’t just dump to stdout, and can be routed to a file or other appender and conveniently enabled and disabled. But it turns out it’s easy to toggle logSql SQL console logging. Get a reference to the sessionFactory bean (e.g. using dependency injection with def sessionFactory) and turn it on with

```
sessionFactory.settings.sqlStatementLogger.logToStdout = true

and off with

sessionFactory.settings.sqlStatementLogger.logToStdout = false
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had Log4j set up but without it this would be a faster way to get some debug info. Thanks.